# What is the normal range of battery drain with ignition off?

Tags: electrical

Assuming the car is in prefect order, the only drain on the battery, when the ignition is off, is from ancillary systems.  Does anyone have an estimate of what the drain is from:

- the radio
- the anti-theft system
- the clock
- the GPS
- others?

I suspect it depends also on how old the car is, as these systems are improved and miniaturized every year.

Comment: Many "old" cars only had a clock and some did not even have that so the drain when off was exactly zero...

Comment: I think you'd be better off measuring this for your specific case. What car did you have in mind? Someone here might have the same and can ballpark it, if your battery is going flat prematurely

Comment: In general 50mA or less (total), is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I have an upper bound estimate. My 2016 Toyota RAV4 hybrid switches its smart key system to a power saving mode after 14 days, after which there's a small delay for opening the door and also only the driver's door handle works. If we assume the battery is 56 Ah, the consumption is at most 56 Ah / (14*24 h) = 0.17 A, assuming the battery would be empty after 14 days (which would mean the power saving mode is pointless).

In practice, the load is much less than 0.17 A. I would say that even 0.1 A would be excessive.

Of course, this depends on what features your car has. For example, a smart key system uses quite a lot of the car battery energy, because it needs to continuously ping the key.

Radio, clock and GPS consume minimal amounts of energy. The radio just needs power to keep its settings in memory. Computer CMOS clocks run for 10 years on a small coin cell battery, so there's no technical reason for having any significant clock consumption in a car. The GPS receiver is obviously switched off.

My car's owner's manual says that the car should be driven once every few months. If we assume "few" means "3", consumption would be 56 Ah / (3*30*24 h) = 0.026 A.